# RPi3 would not start (red led on always), but then it started without any explanation

Tags: pi-3b+

Yesterday, electricity went down at the location where I have an RPi3 setup. After electricity came back, the pi did not start. I went to see what's happening with the pi, and indeed, the red led was on (and the green one not).

I tried a couple of times to restart it, without any hope. I thought I would just have to replace the microSD card.

Every night, a programable socket restarts the router, modem and the RPi3. It seems that this morning the pi is up an running again.

So, what was the reason yesterday it did not start?

In my experience with Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 this is the frustrating fact that I often had: it just freezes unexpectedly and cannot get that ~100% up & running time.

---

Would it work to set up an UPS, to prevent the electricty to stop from the pi and program the pi to shutdown nicely right before the socket would anyway turn it off?

```
[Electricity] ---> UPS ---> Programable Socket ---> Raspberrry Pi 3
Sometimes         Always     Off: 2AM-2:15AM        Cronjob: 
Interrupts         ON                               Shutdown at 1:50AM
```

So, this would cover the cases when electricity interrupts (because the UPS would be always on). Then, every night at:

- 1:50 AM: the pi would shut down nicely
- 2:00 AM: the programmable socket stops power
- 2:15 AM: the programmable socket starts power again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much what I answered here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133140/33613

That happened in my case when the file system got corrupted and the device won't start anymore.

Reinstalling the OS and setting up the UPS device helped.